# How to secure the Javascript Code?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to prevent your javascripts being stolen,copied, and viewed ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660060/how-to-prevent-your-javascripts-being-stolen-copied-and-viewed)

What is the best way to secure the javascript code & make it hard to understand it and for sure steal it... I know that its impossible to secure it 100% since its client side and all the code the client can see it.. But I need to make it as hard as possible...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you can do is minify and obfuscate it.

Here is [a free obfuscator](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx), there are several around.

Answer (score 4):

First, obfuscate it - change functions/variables names to meaningless names. Then pack it using the [packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/).

Comment: If do that.. obfuscate it then packer it... is it easy to deobfuscate it.. or it needs time to do that ??

I use the tool that "Tom Gullen"(Thank u ;) ) mention it ..

Comment: Also...

Someone, told me a really also nice way to secure the code.. by securing the obfuscate with a key... I mean securing the secured already :)

is it possible to do that, secure the code with a key & obfuscate it ??

thanks very much Guys, for ur help

Answer (score 3):

100% securing of JS code is impossible. Whichever popular packer you use, [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) is usually able to reconstruct a humanly-readable source from it. Personally, I only use [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) which is the best minifier/optimizer currently available.

Comment: if its impossible 100%... how can i make it at least harder for normal user ?? since no matter what I obfuscate it, http://jsbeautifier.org/ will do the trick and deobfuscate it :) 
it will take a second to do that :)

and for the Google Closure Compiler. they said that it only make your code run faster, they didn't mention any thing for securing and encrypting !!

What should I do ?? I just want it hard for a normal user to see it, since the hacker no matter what I did they will see it eventually :)