# How can I prevent users from using my AppId and JavaScript key to generate new users?

Tags: security, parse-platform

I am building a website with a Parse backend. So I'm building register/login right now, and am thinking that users can take the AppId and Javascript key and write their own javascript to register users on their own.

How can I prevent this from happening, is there a way to restrict the IPs where javascript Parse can run?

Comment: See https://parse.com/docs/data#security.  The gist of it is that you can create class-level permissions in the data browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean because the user can look at your javascript and get the variables from there. If thats the case look here for a thread looking at javascript security. [How to prevent your JavaScript code from being stolen, copied, and viewed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660060/how-to-prevent-your-javascript-code-from-being-stolen-copied-and-viewed)

The jist of it seemed to be that it is hard to do.